# Трудности SOAP сериализации

Tags: c#

Есть класс с атрибутом Serializable, некоторые поля которого помечены атрибутом NonSerialized, и есть у этого класса поле с типом bool. Вопрос заключается в следующем: если это поле равно true - сериализуются все поля класса, если false, то те поля, которые помечены как NonSerialized, не сериализуются. Как переопределить атрибуты, чтобы использовать для сериализации SoapFormatter, а не XmlSerializer?

Comment: А в чем вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от флага сериализовались все либо некоторые поля, или как переопределить атрибуты, чтобы использовать SoapFormatter?

Comment: Вопрос в том, в том чтобы в зависимости о значения флага часть полей либо сериализовалась, либо нет.
Вот если бы была возможность извлекать атрибут у поля и менять его на другой, думаю проблема отпала, но я к сожалению этого пока не знаю.
Вот в вашем коде метод AddValue, что делает? Он случайно не задает атрибут?

Comment: Метод AddValue "добавляет логическое значение в хранилище SerializationInfo": http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/013we800.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Класс для сериализации, где поле ToSerialize сериализуется в зависимости от значения флага IsSerialized:

```
[Serializable]
class Some: ISerializable
{
    public bool IsSerialized;
    public string ToSerialize;

    public Some()
    {
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("IsSerialized", IsSerialized);
        if (IsSerialized)
            info.AddValue("ToSerialize", ToSerialize);
    }

    protected Some(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        IsSerialized = info.GetBoolean("IsSerialized");

        if (IsSerialized)
            ToSerialize = info.GetString("ToSerialize");
    }
}
```

Сам код сериализации:

```
Some some = new Some();
Stream stream = File.Open("data.xml", FileMode.Create);
SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();

formatter.Serialize(stream, some);
stream.Close();
some = null;
```

PS: Код не тестировался.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем! Кажется разобрался. Выкладываю полный код своей программы.

```
[Serializable]
public class Bill: ISerializable
{
    static private readonly float PayDay;
    private readonly int _countDay;
    static private readonly float FineDelayPay;
    private readonly int _countDayDelayPay;
    private readonly float _sumPay;
    private readonly float _fine;
    private readonly float _totalSumPay;

    static Bill()
    {
        PayDay = 1.43f;
        FineDelayPay = 0.02f;
    }

    public Bill(int countDay, int countDayDelayPay, bool debug)
    {
        DebugProp = debug;
        _countDay = countDay;
        _countDayDelayPay = countDayDelayPay;
        _sumPay = PayDay * _countDay;
        _fine = FineDelayPay * _countDayDelayPay;
        _totalSumPay = _sumPay + _fine;
    }
    public Bill(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        _countDay = info.GetInt32("_countDay");
        _countDayDelayPay = info.GetInt32("_countDayDelayPay");
        if(!DebugProp)
        {
            _sumPay = PayDay * _countDay;
            _fine = FineDelayPay * _countDayDelayPay;
            _totalSumPay = _sumPay + _fine;
            return;
        }
        _sumPay = (float)info.GetValue("_sumPay", _sumPay.GetType());
        _fine = (float)info.GetValue("_fine", _fine.GetType());
        _totalSumPay = (float)info.GetValue("_totalSumPay", _totalSumPay.GetType());
    }

    public static bool DebugProp { get; set; }

   public override string ToString()
   {
        var arr = new[]
                      {
                          "Платеж за день: {0}\n", "Количество дней: {1}\n", "Штраф за один день просрочки: {2}\n",
                          "Количество дней просрочки: {3}\n", "Сумма к оплате без штрафа: {4}\n",
                          "Сумма штрафа: {5}\n",
                          "Итого: {6}"
                      };
        var fullstr = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
        {
            fullstr += arr[i];
        }
        return string.Format(fullstr, PayDay, _countDay, FineDelayPay, _countDayDelayPay,
                            _sumPay, _fine, _totalSumPay);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("_countDay", _countDay);
        info.AddValue("_countDayDelayPay", _countDayDelayPay);
        info.AddValue("PayDay",PayDay);
        info.AddValue("FineDelayPay",FineDelayPay);

        if (!DebugProp) return;
        info.AddValue("_sumPay", _sumPay);
        info.AddValue("_fine",_fine);
        info.AddValue("_totalSumPay", _totalSumPay);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Для полной сериализации объекта нажмите Enter");
        Console.WriteLine("Для сериализвции без вычисляемых полей нажмите любую клавишу");
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        var obj = key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter ? new Bill(30,10, true) : new Bill(30,10, false);
        var filename = key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter ? "fileFull" : "file" ;
        var fs = new FileStream(@"I:\"+filename+".soap", FileMode.Create);
        var sf = new SoapFormatter();
        sf.Serialize(fs, obj);
        fs.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Для просмотра записанной информации нажмите любую клавишу");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        var newfs = new FileStream(@"I:\" + filename + ".soap", FileMode.Open);
        obj = (Bill)sf.Deserialize(newfs);
        Console.Write(obj.ToString());
        newfs.Close();
    }
}
```